# iPhone - Configure Position of Text In Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UITableView with multiple cells. I want to align things sort of like a receipt.

i.e. 
Title------------Price

where Title is aligned left and Price is aligned right.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your cells, use `-[UITableViewCell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIndicator:Cell];`  According to the documentation:

> **UITableViewCellStyleValue1**
>   A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with left-aligned and black text; on the right side is a label that has smaller blue text and is right-aligned. The Settings application uses cells in this style.

Then you can use the `cell.textLabel` and `cell.detailTextLabel` properties to set the text and modify the font and text color of the two labels.

Comment: Trying it out now and will post back.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually position the labels in the cell. The left alignment is obvious, to do the right alignment you can calculate the width of the text with `-[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:]` and set the X coordinate of the right label in the cell with `cellWidth-textWidth-rightMargin`.